# How can I find my Samsung Galaxy S5 without internet, or access to Android Device Manager?

Tags: email, samsung-galaxy-s-5, lost-phone

I have a Samsung Galaxy S5 that just recently went missing. However, I do not know what email address I made for the Google Account on my phone. I was told I could use Android Device Manager if my phone was connected to the internet & I had to be signed into the Google Account that I had set up on my phone. I do not know the email I used, & I also know for a fact that where my phone is (yes, i'm pretty sure I know who took it) that it isn't connected to the internet. I also have no plan on it right, no minutes, time, no data, no way for it to pick up internet unless it's in Wifi. I was only able to get it to connect to one Wifi near the place where I'm thinking it was stolen. I know it's on, but I'm not sure how much longer my battery is going to last. I really, really need to figure out a way to find my phone. Please any help, or advice is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I find out what my google email address is that I set my phone up with, without having my phone?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/157228/how-do-i-find-out-what-my-google-email-address-is-that-i-set-my-phone-up-with-w)

Answer (score 0):

0
down vote
I believe that when you signed up your phone,system email,you must provide an alternative email address for p/w & user name recovery as is common w/Google & most effective email providers. Click on "Gmail"-tab, while on Google Chrome homepage browser,(using a desktop windows pc prefferably) try your best guess at the username, hit enter and under the sign in popup window there should be either "use a different. Account" or "Forgot user name/password"? Click on that and it should tell you something like, "Recovery email,Google will send you an email containing a one time verification code to xxx.....@xxx whatever the alternative email account you used when you set up your phone. If not,then I,might suspect of your true ownership of this phone you speak of. Hope this helps.